# can not apply operator * to operand of type decimal and double

Tags: c#

Hi I need to apply a discount of 5.2% on a product.I have tryed doing something like this:

```
decimal BasePrice {get;set;}
decimal Discount = (BasePrice * 5.2) / 100;
```

But Visual Studio tells me that it :

> can not apply operator '*' to operand of type decimal and double

If that is so how can I represent this discount?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
decimal Discount = (BasePrice * 5.2m) / 100;
```

Otherwise, `5.2` will be treated as a double.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M