# Operator '/' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double' - NCalc

Tags: c#, .net, exception, casting, ncalc

I'm trying to run this formula in NCalc:

```
"( Abs([a] - [b]) / ( ([a] + [b]) / 2.0 ) ) * 100"
```

I get the error:

```
Operator '/' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double'
```

The [a] and [b] parameters are passed as Decimals. I tried putting 'm' on the 2 and 100 like so:

```
"( Abs([a] - [b]) / ( ([a] + [b]) / 2m ) ) * 100m"
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Additional information: extraneous input 'm' expecting ')' at line 1:36
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943794/can-not-apply-operator-to-operand-of-type-decimal-and-double), but it didn't help me. The same question posted on [codeplex](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/244043) with no answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround is to pass `2m` as parameter to make it recognized properly as a `decimal` value, for example :

```
string strExp = "( Abs([a] - [b]) / ( ([a] + [b]) / [c] ) ) * 100";
Expression e = new Expression(strExp);

e.Parameters["a"] = 3.5m;
e.Parameters["b"] = 1m;
e.Parameters["c"] = 2m;   //<- pass 2m as expression parameter
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not sure, but I thought C# is acceptable because one question OP followed is about plain C#, not NCalc : "I followed this question...". And `2m` compiled and produced a result for me (didn't check if the calculation result is correct though)