# Operator '+' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double' - NCalc

Tags: c#, .net, ncalc

I'm using [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com) to evaluate complex expressions. But I've found a major problem.

A simple formula like `new Expression("Abs(-1) + Cos(2)").Evaluate()` throws the exception

```
Operator '+' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double
```

In C# code `Math.Abs(-1) + Math.Cos(2)` works, so either I'm doing something wrong or there is a bug in NCalc.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Does anyone have a solution?

The only thread i found on the project's website related to this error is quite old and talks about editing the source code.
https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/346702

I also posted a question on their forum but StackOverflow is usualy more dynamic.
https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/613634

Comment: have you tried to search this error at first?

Comment: you need to convert them to same type.

Comment: @btevfik, how do you suggest i do this?

Comment: does this work 

new Expression("Abs(-1m) + Cos(2m)").Evaluate()

Comment: @btevfik and everyone. Please dont just throw solutions. If you have never used and dont know NCalc you wont understand the question. 1º I can't pass  -1m e 2m because they are not valid numbers. 2º The problem is not the Abs and Cos functions. Its the sum.

Comment: ???? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191073/operator-cant-be-applied-to-operands-of-types-decimal-and-double-ncal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I looked at the source code. And here is what I found.

The Abs(-1) part of the expression is always evaluated as a decimal

```
Result = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(
                        Evaluate(function.Expressions[0]))
                        );
```

Cos(2) is evaluated as double

```
Result = Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(Evaluate(function.Expressions[0])));
```

And C# does not allow you to add these two types together.

The reason that `Math.Abs(-1) + Math.Cos(2)` works is that Math.Abs(-1) actually evaluates as int. And you can perfectly add an int to double.

You can not compile this piece for example (note m for decimal). `Math.Abs(-1m) + Math.Cos(2);`
which is actually what NCalc is trying to do when you type out

```
new Expression("Abs(-1) + Cos(2)").Evaluate()
```

I would call this a bug. You can try to edit the source and try to fix this problem or find some other option.

Comment: Thanks. The project although stable and usable, seems a bit abandoned. I guess the only option is to try to fix this

Comment: It appears the issue has been solved already. its just not deployed as a version https://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/5a719518101d

Comment: I saw that the issue was solved in the latest source but not deployed anywhere, so i created a clone in [github](https://github.com/pitermarx/ncalc-edge), linked to [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pitermarx/ncalc-edge) and published to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalc-Edge/)

I also [started](https://github.com/pitermarx/ncalc2) a new [project](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pitermarx/ncalc2) that intends to [upgrade](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalc2) antlr to version 4

Answer (score 0):

After a brief [chat with btevfik](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73782/) (helpfull fella) we have come to the conclusion that this is a bug in NCalc.
I guess I'll have to analyse the source and fix it.

I still accept answers though...