# Mathematical expression in string: Alternatives to NCalc

Tags: c#, string, math, expression, ncalc

I need to read from file mathematical expression and evaluate it's value. Example expression formats are as follow:

- `"5"` - constant
- `"3.1415 * 0.25"` - constant expressions
- `"{0} - 50"` - expressions with value placeholders (`String.Format()`)
- `"Abs({0} - 50)"` - just like up but with mathematical functions

I was using so far NCalc which worked great until it had to deal with expressions like follow:

- `"3.0 * Abs({0} + 34)"`

Unfortunately in example just above the result of following code:

```
var value = ReadValueFromSomewhere(); // Lets say it returns 125.75
var exprStr = ReadExpression(); // returns: "3.0 * Abs({0} + 34)"
var toEval = String.Format(exprStr, value);
var result = new NCCalc.Expression(toEval).Evaluate()
```

is following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Operator '*' can't be applied to operands of types 'double' and 'decimal' 
>   NCalc.Numbers.Multiply(object, object)
>   NCalc.Domain.EvaluationVisitor.Visit(NCalc.Domain.BinaryExpression)
>   NCalc.Domain.BinaryExpression.Accept(NCalc.Domain.LogicalExpressionVisitor)
>   NCalc.Expression.Evaluate()

It seems like Abs() method returns decimal and NCalc can't handle doing calculations between `double` and `decimal` (propably bug?). So I would like to ask what alternative libraries I could use instead of NCalc? Or perhaps there is other workaround than expression:

- `"Abs(3.0) * Abs({0} + 34)"`

?

Comment: Seems like it is a bug. Here is a question from 2 years ago about the very issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29255487/4996248 . That question links to this forum which suggests a workaround: https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/346702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "expressions with value placeholders"? Can you give more specific example? You can try [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) - it works for Java and .NET.

Example of usage:

```
Expression e = new Expression("3.1415 * 0.25");
double v = e.calculate();
```

Follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/).

Regards

Comment: As in my post: `Abs(3.0) * Abs({0} + 34)`. 
I use `{0}` to insert double type value by `String.Format`. I'll take a look at mXparser - thanks.

Comment: Instead of {0} you can use user defined argument or user defined constant  - i.e. http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/user-defined-arguments/ or http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/user-defined-constants/